# Configuration of Subversion in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2

I want to configure SVN on my computer.
For that how would I create a repository?
How to give all the paths needed?
I am using Mac os 10.7.3 Lion and Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 5):

To setup your Subversion repository in XCode 4, go to File → Source Control → Manage Repositories. Once there, you will see an option to add a repository:
[image]

After selecting Add Repository option, you will need to enter your Subversion repository URL and the name you wish to add to your repository:

[image]

Click next, and on next step you should see an option to setup paths to your folders in your svn repository. There are three folders which are usually created by default when you use svn, and they are called /trunk, /tags, /branches. In case you don't have this folders, you can skip this step, it's optional.

[image]

Now you should see in XCode organizer your repository in the sidebar. What we would like to do is add one of our projects to Subversion so we can use version control for the project. We would like to add the project to /trunk folder of our repository. In order to do this, click on the /trunk folder, and then click on the import button.

[image]

When you click import, select the folder of files which you would like to import. Then you will be prompted to enter a commit message. After this, click refresh, and you should see the new files added to your repository.

[image]

Now your project is under version control, and you should be able to see it in your Beanstalk account, in your repository. All you need to do now is checkout the files to a location of your preference, and open the project from this location.

When you open the project, you will see flags next to all files you modify, add or delete and you will see an option to commit the files.

[image]
May this Helping to you

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks neon,
But here Problem is i am trying to Importing project from My Local System.
And it is giving me Following error

svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file://localhost/Volumes/UNTITLED2/I-Sight%20Workspace/FFReporting/trunk/FFReporting'

What should I do now??
Please do the needful.

Comment: You need a third '/' before the drive letter:file:///localhost/Volumes/UNTITLED2/I-Sight%20Workspace/FFReporting/trunk/FFRepo‌​rting'

Comment: I am directly entering Location path from Volumes/UNTITLED2/I-Sight%20Workspace/FFReporting/trunk‌​/FFRepo‌​rting.
So, I never been asked to entering that 3rd "/" while adding a repository.!!
Now, What to do?

Comment: while "importing" project folder into "trunk" i am getting.. svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL #pls help.

Comment: Its a copy of, http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/95579-setting-up-subversion-with-xcode-4